# Change MSE logo in bounty email notifications

Tags: feature-request, bug, meta, email, logo

In the past, bounty email notifications from MSE had the general Stack Exchange logo:

> [image]

This is fine.

However, today I noticed a change which doesn't look good:

> [image]

The transparent logo doesn't fit with the light gray background. Can it please be changed either back to SE logo, or add a blue-ish background same as on MSE site?