# New logo in Bounty Email is squished vertically

Tags: bug, design, bounties, email

Related: [Change MSE logo in bounty email notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316769/change-mse-logo-in-bounty-email-notifications)

This new logo has since gone funky:

> [image]