# Meta emails have weird aspect ratio

Tags: bug, meta, images, email

*This problem and the regular aspect ratios for non-Meta emails were tested in both Chrome and Firefox on my Mac.*

---

So I got this email about Meta automatically, and the aspect ratio is very, very off:

[image]

This problem only applies to Meta emails, that I know of;  [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hleD.png), [Stack Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TwCo.png), and [Arqade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boGpu.png) don't have this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New logo in Bounty Email is squished vertically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318094/new-logo-in-bounty-email-is-squished-vertically)...this is the *exact* same bug you're reporting, but it was was marked as a duplicate of the above issue by a CM.